What is the Delta Flyer's top warp speed?
In 2375 the crew of the Voyager teamed up to build the Delta Flyer which is shown going to warp multiple times during Voyager's seven season run. The original Delta Flyer was destroyed in 2377 and a second one was built.
What is the Delta Flyer's (either one) top warp speed?

Pre or post Borg enhancements?

@JiminyCricket Pre and Post there must be a difference.

@LucasWinslow - After they received a Borg coil, they were capable of transwarp. That would be off the warp scale

@Valorum They only had the Borg coil for a limited amount of time before it ran out of charge.

Ludicrous speed?

@Agarza What? You've got the wrong universe. This question is about the Star Trek universe specificly Voyager's Delta Flyer a shuttle that Voyager's crew built while in the Delta Quadrent after they releized that normal shuttles just wouldn't cut it in the increasingly dangrus Delta Quadrent.

It's something you'll see here from time to time, comedy memes. xkcd (wink) is a frequent flyer. @LucasWinslow

@LucasWinslow - What about that episode where Janeway and Paris went to plaid...

@Valorum That was warp 10 and they used the shuttle Crocrene not the Delta Flyer. I usually don't talk about that episode and I NEVER refer to it by name.

Per the Starship Spotter guide to various Starfleet vessels, the ship's cruising speed is Warp 3 and the top speed is a very respectable Warp 6


Given Voyager's maximum speed was over warp 9 (ignoring discussions about cruising & top speed) and warp is (probably) logarithmic, warp 6 doesn't seem particularly fast. How does that compare to other shuttles of that era?

@Druckles - The larger Runabouts in DS9 were limited to about warp 4.7. The Cochrane and Dawkins (assigned to Voyager) topped out at about warp 4.0.

Alright, that's very respectable.
